# LINQ Group list and count how many values exist for each distinct group

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have a list of people

```cs
var data = new Person[]{
    new Person{
        Gender = "male",
        Age = 7,
    },
    new Person{
        Gender = "female",
        Age = 14,
    },
    new Person{
        Gender = "male",
        Age = 12,
    },
    new Person{
        Gender = "male",
        Age = 8,
    },
    new Person{
        Gender = "male",
        Age = 18,
    },
    new Person{
        Gender = "female",
        Age = 18,
    },
    new Person{
        Gender = "male",
        Age = 7,
    }
};
```

I want to group it into age-range so that each range shows the count of male and female under it.

I have tried this:

```cs
var grouped = data.GroupBy(d => new { age = 5 * (d.Age / 5), d.Gender }).Select(d => new
{
    range = $"{d.Key.age}-{d.Key.age + 4}",
    male = d.Count(x => x.Gender == "male"),
    female =  d.Count(x => x.Gender == "female")

}).Dump("grouped");
```

and I get this

| range | male | female |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5-9 | 3 | 0 |
| 10-14 | 0 | 1 |
| 10-14 | 1 | 0 |
| 15-19 | 1 | 0 |
| 15-19 | 0 | 1 |

but I want this

| range | male | female |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5-9 | 30 | 0 |
| 10-14 | 1 | 1 |
| 15-19 | 1 | 1 |

How do I go about it please?

Comment: why do you group by gender?

Comment: Well, you did group by the tuple (age, gender). If you don't want the groups separated by gender, then why did you make gender part of the grouping key?

Comment: @CSharpie thank you! I didn't notice that. ‍♂️ I removed the group by gender and it works.